# Would this be an effective way to study and comprehend text's?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, education

This is probably a grey area question but I am going to test the waters anyway.

What I am thinking of doing would be to basically record myself doing examples from textbooks and making lessons for myself which I can then view later and possibly post them online. Sort of like the Feynman method I guess which is to pretend you are teaching someone. I have read other places that the best way to learn math is to teach it.

Would this be a good way to get maximum comprehension from Math Text's? Since it would activate all the methods of learning and I would eventually develop a pretty extensive reference collection for later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's a fine idea: "*Whatever works!*"

Seriously, the ***accountability*** that teaching inevitably incurs (**and** the accountability in terms of having to watch yourself teaching!) are both excellent ideas.

Perhaps you can get both immediate feedback and "view-at-a-later-time" feedback by finding a friend, or a handful of friends, with whom you can experiment "teaching one another" - with or without videotaping. You can then learn from others' success (and failures), as well as your own.

Both of the above: "teaching the class" (e.g., scheduled presentations to the class) and viewing yourself "teaching in action" are pedagogical strategies employed successfully by many instructors.

You might also want to think about blogging: many successful students opt to "go public" with their work, through on-line blogging, which offers a similar sort of "accountability."

Comment: Thanks for your response :)

Comment: You're welcome. I like the idea!

Comment: @amWhy: Glad to hear it! It is so odd to have cyber MSE stalkers about.